# Pygame enemy not staying at the intended position on the map

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,-16,2,512)
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('THE GAME')#Window name

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('player_animations/R1.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R2.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R3.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R4.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R5.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R6.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R7.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R8.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('player_animations/L1.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L2.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L3.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L4.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L5.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L6.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L7.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L8.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L9.png')]

Window_SIZE = (900,600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Window_SIZE,0,32)

display = pygame.Surface((900,600))

player_image = pygame.image.load('player_animations/player_image.png')
player_image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

grass_image = pygame.image.load('Map/Grassblock.png')
grass_image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

dirt_image = pygame.image.load('Map/Dirtblock.png')

cobble_image = pygame.image.load('Map/Stoneblock.png')

TILE_SIZE = grass_image.get_width()

true_scroll = [0,0]

#ENEMIES
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction
        self.move_counter += 1
        if self.move_counter > 50:
            self.move_direction *= -1
            self.move_counter = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    screen.blit(display,(0,0))
    blob_group.draw(screen)
    blob_group.update()
    

    if walkCount + 1 >=  27:
        walkCount = 0

    if moving_left:
        screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3],(player_rect.x-scroll[0],player_rect.y-scroll[1] ))
        walkCount += 1
            
    elif moving_right:
        screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3],(player_rect.x-scroll[0],player_rect.y-scroll[1] ))
        walkCount += 1  


    else:
        screen.blit(player_image,(player_rect.x-scroll[0],player_rect.y-scroll[1]))     
    


    pygame.display.update() 
    


def load_map(path):
    f = open(path + '.txt','r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = data.split('\n')
    game_map = []
    for row in data:
        game_map.append(list(row))
    return game_map         

game_map = load_map('Map/map')

background_objects = [[0.2,[500,200,250,3000]],[0.5,[750,30,200,4000]],[0.3,[1000,100,235,2000]],[0.5,[130,90,100,4000]],[0.6,[300,100,220,5000]]]

def collision_test(rect,tiles):
    hit_list = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
    return hit_list
    
def move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types = {'top':False,'bottom':False,'right':False,'left':False}
    rect.x += movement[0]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0] > 0:
            rect.right = tile.left
            collision_types['right'] = True
        elif movement[0] < 0:
            rect.left = tile.right
            collision_types['left'] = True
    rect.y += movement[1]           
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1] > 0:
            rect.bottom = tile.top
            collision_types['bottom'] = True
        elif movement[1] < 0:
            rect.top = tile.bottom
            collision_types['top'] = True   

    return rect, collision_types


moving_right = False
moving_left = False

moving_down = False

player_y_momentum = 0
air_timer = 0

player_rect = pygame.Rect(50,50,player_image.get_width(),player_image.get_height())

player_left = False
player_right = False
player_down = False 

jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('jump.wav')
grass_sound = [pygame.mixer.Sound('grass_0.wav'),pygame.mixer.Sound('grass_1.wav')]

pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)



walkCount = 0

vel = 5

true_scroll[0] += (player_rect.x - true_scroll[0]-450)/20
true_scroll[1] += (player_rect.y - true_scroll[1]-364)/20
 
scroll = true_scroll.copy()
scroll[0] = int(scroll[0])
scroll[1] = int(scroll[1])

blob_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
tile_rects = []
for y, row in enumerate(game_map):
    for x, tile in enumerate(row):
        if tile != '0': 
           tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE))
        if tile == '4':
            blob = Enemy(x*TILE_SIZE,y*TILE_SIZE+2)
            blob_group.add(blob)

#Game loop
while True:
    display.fill((146,244,255))

    true_scroll[0] += (player_rect.x - true_scroll[0]-450)/20
    true_scroll[1] += (player_rect.y - true_scroll[1]-364)/20
 
    scroll = true_scroll.copy()
    scroll[0] = int(scroll[0])
    scroll[1] = int(scroll[1])

    pygame.draw.rect(display,(7,80,75),pygame.Rect(0,400,900,600))
    for background_object in background_objects:
        obj_rect = pygame.Rect(background_object[1][0]-scroll[0]*background_object[0],background_object[1][1]-scroll[1]*background_object[0],background_object[1][2],background_object[1][3])
        if background_objects[0] == 0.5:
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),obj_rect)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(9,91,85),obj_rect)    

    for y, row in enumerate(game_map):
        for x, tile in enumerate(row):
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(dirt_image,(x*TILE_SIZE-scroll[0],y*TILE_SIZE-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '2':
                display.blit(grass_image,(x*TILE_SIZE-scroll[0],y*TILE_SIZE-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '3':
                display.blit(cobble_image,(x*TILE_SIZE-scroll[0],y*TILE_SIZE-scroll[1]))            
       
    player_movement = [0,0]
    if moving_right:
        player_movement[0] += vel
    if moving_left:
        player_movement[0] -= vel
    #________________________________________
    if moving_down:
        player_movement[1] += 7

    #________________________________________       
    player_movement[1] += player_y_momentum 
    player_y_momentum += 0.2
    if player_y_momentum > 3:   
        player_y_momentum = 3
      

    player_rect,collisions = move(player_rect,player_movement,tile_rects)           

    if collisions['bottom']:
        player_y_momentum = 0
        air_timer = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 1


    if collisions['top']:
        player_y_momentum = 0
        air_timer = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 0.1


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
                player_right = True
                player_left = False
                player_down = False

            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
                player_left = True
                player_right = False
                player_down = False

            #_________________________
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = True
                player_down = True
                player_left = False
                player_right = False


            
            else:
                player_right = False
                player_left = False
                player_down = False
                walkCount = 0   

            if event.key == K_UP:
                if air_timer < 6:
                    player_y_momentum = -7.5
                    player_right = False
                    player_left = False
                    player_down = False
                    walkCount = 0
                    jump_sound.play()
                    jump_sound.set_volume(0.1)



        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
                
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False 

            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = False
            
        
    
                
    
    redrawGameWindow()  
    

    surf = pygame.transform.scale(display,Window_SIZE)
    clock.tick(54)
```

I have made my enemy move back and forth but they are moving in respect to my player.
They are not staying on the map instead.
As my camera moves with the player the enemies also move in the same direction, i want them to stay at a single spot.

Comment: by each time calling the `redrawGameWindow` function, position of all enemies should be updated? is this what this function do?

Comment: I assume this line "obj_rect = pygame.Rect(background_object[1][0]-scroll[0]*background_object[0],background_object[1][1]-scroll[1]*background_object[0],background_object[1][2],background_object[1][3])" repositions the tile rects in relation to the camera?  You need to do the same for the enemies.

Comment: Yes the redrawGameWindow function updates the position of the enemies and the player animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the player is corrected by `scroll`. You also need to correct the position of the enemies. Remove `blob_group.draw(screen)` from the `redrawGameWindow` function, but draw the enemies in a loop:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    
    if walkCount + 1 >=  27:
        walkCount = 0
    current_play_image = player_image
    if moving_left:
        current_play_image = walkLeft[walkCount // 3]
        walkCount += 1    
    elif moving_right:
        current_play_image = walkRight[walkCount // 3]
        walkCount += 1  

    blob_group.update()
    
    screen.blit(display,(0,0))
    for enemy in blob_group:
        screen.blit(enemy.image, (enemy.rect.x-scroll[0], enemy.rect.y-scroll[1]))    
    screen.blit(current_play_image, (player_rect.x-scroll[0], player_rect.y-scroll[1]))
    pygame.display.update()
```